# Python3 http request close connection when nothing is sent

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests

I have an API that have the following workaround:

1. You make a POST request and it returns "n" lines of data:{json}
2. It mantain the connection opened until 300 seconds minimum without sending nothing.

As this is very slow, I want to find a way to close the connection when is not sending anything or after a timer.

Comment: Can't you just use `timeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, it was easier than what I thought, i'm going to copy paste here my code using `http.client` library:

```py
def asyncCall(url, data = None, timeout = 300,):
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(IP, timeout=timeout)
    conn.request("POST", url, bytes(json.dumps(data), encoding="utf-8"), )
    r1 = conn.getresponse()
    while not r1.closed:
        l = r1.readline().decode("utf-8")
        yield l
```

On this way, it can pass each line of code to a callback (that run in a separated `Process`) and close the connection after `timeout`.